# How to draw multiple Squares in OpenGLES2

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es-2.0

I have an array that holds x,y of multiple squares, every 4 consecutive x,y in the array are vertices of square, how to draw this buffer in openGLES2?
I want to draw squares separately not connected to each other. (I am coding in Objective -c if that matters.)

Many thanks in advance.